# Is there any use of ruby combined comparison operator/spaceship operator other than in sorting?

Tags: ruby, sorting, spaceship-operator

Ruby's combined comparison operator, or spaceship operator, is used in sorting. I used this operator with `sort` function, and cannot understand the mechanism of this operator. Are there any other uses of this operator?

Comment: It technically isn't an operator, but a method that you define.

This means that "any other use" is up to you to imagine and design.

So the answer to your question, as written, is "Yes".

Answer (score 5):

You are basically asking if two values are greater than, less than, or equal to, all in one operator. You could use it to return a value to tell a method to increment, decrement, or do nothing.

```
1 <=> 3 returns -1
3 <=> 1 returns 1
3 <=> 3 returns 0
```

For example if you had a score keeping method that awarded one point for a game you win, minus one point for a game you lose, or no change for a tie...

```
def score(player_1, player_2, current_score)
  current_score + player_1 <=> player_2
end
```

so...

```
score(1,2,0)
#=> -1
score(1,3,-1)
#=> -2
score(3,2,-2)
#=> -1
score(3,0,-1)
#=> 0
score(4,0,0)
#=> 1
score(3,0,1)
#=> 2
score(3,3,2)
#=> 2
```

Comment: Another common use is in a `case` statement. For example, `case a<=>b; when -1 then ...; when 0 then ...; when 1 then ... ;.end`.

Comment: `current_score` is a local variable. It does not make sense to assign to it using `+=`. You should just have`+`.

Answer (score 0):

The spaceship operator is needed for the [Comparable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html). Basically: `include Comparable`in your class, define a `<=>`method on this class and  the >, <=, < , >=, == , and between? methods are automatically defined for that class.